Sentry doesn't send errors
I'm setting up Sentry on my project. I need arbitrary messages and exceptions to appear in the logs.
I do everything according to the instructions, but it doesn't work.
Sentry 23.8.0
PHP 7.4 (PHP, Nginx, Apache)
Composer:
sentry/sentry 4.6.1
sentry/sdk 4.0.0

\Sentry\init([
   'dsn' => '********'
]);

\Sentry\captureMessage('Test Message');

try {
   throw new \Exception('My error');
} catch (\Throwable $exception) {
   Sentry\captureException($exception);
}

Page loading, no errors on server, but Senty is empty.
(Errors are sent to the cloud sentry)

Sentry stops receiving data in several cases:

not enough RAM
not enough disk space


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Your answer pertains to Self Hosted Sentry, OP has since updated their question clarifying they are using Sentry Cloud so this answer is not applicable.
